# javascript unexepected end of input error I cannot find why

Tags: javascript, frontend, fetch, jinja2

I made a function with a fetch and it shows no errors until I run it. When I run it I get the error below. I ran it through jshint and jslint and they do not show any issues. This is pretty much a copy/paste of a function I have that works fine. Do you all see anything wrong?

Error from browser

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (admin:429:59)
```

```
this.element.querySelector("#product-btn").addEventListener("click", async function(e) {
    // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    form=document.getElementById('product-upload');
    const fields = {
        csrf_token: {
            input: document.getElementById('csrf_token'),
            error: document.getElementById('csrf_token-error')
        },
        title: {
            input: document.getElementById('title'),
            error: document.getElementById('title-error')
        },
        description: {
            input: document.getElementById('description'),
            error: document.getElementById('description-error')
        },
        cost: {
            input: document.getElementById('cost'),
            error: document.getElementById('cost-error')
        },
        old_cost: {
            input: document.getElementById('old_cost'),
            error: document.getElementById('old_cost-error')
        }
    };
    //This shows error in lint but it's jinja for python and works fine
    const response = await fetch('{{ url_for('main.upload_products') }}', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
          csrf_token: fields.csrf_token.input.value,
          title: fields.title.input.value,
          description: fields.description.input.value,
          cost: fields.cost.input.value,
          old_cost: fields.old_cost.input.value
      })
    });
    //THE code below is where the error points to
    data = await response.json();
    if (response.ok) {
        myDropzone.processQueue();
    } else {
        const errors = data;
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
        Object.keys(errors).forEach((key) => {
            fields[key].input.classList.add('is-invalid');
            fields[key].error.innerHTML = errors[key][0];
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Try looking at the JSON you are trying to parse in the Network tab

Comment: Although it is unlikely to be the case of your problem [implicit globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) make code much harder to maintain.

Comment: The error relates to your JSON, not your code. Also (unrelated), you have your check on `response.ok` in the wrong place. It should be *before* you call `json()`, not after.

Comment: I found the issue. For my eventlistener it was set to 'click' changing it to 'submit' made it work as predicted. The wtforms validators fire on submit and the form works with this. The json I had worked fine, but for some reason with 'click' it ignores my forms logic.